# Retrieve the names and birthdates of all people from the "people" table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I would like to get the names from a user table if the users' birthday is today.

**User table**

```
name  |   date of birth
------+-----------------
name1 |   20/05/1991
name2 |   05/01/1995
name3 |   05/01/1991
```

If I supply: `05/01/2015` as parameter, it should display `name2` and `name3`.

Can anyone tell me the SQL query required for filtering the results by the date parameter.

Comment: what is the data type of "date of birth" column?

Comment: @praveen-prasannan- datetime

Comment: How do you wish to deal with users with a DOB of Feb 29th in non-leap years? Ignore them? Or include them on the 28th Feb or 1st Mar? Or something else?

Answer (score 14):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT NAME, [DATE OF BIRTH]
FROM TABLE
WHERE DAY([DATE OF BIRTH]) = DAY(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH([DATE OF BIRTH]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/845a9/1) with the query based on your sample data.

My initial answer was incorrect because it was actually looking for the same date between `GETDATE()` with the `DATE OF BIRTH` which is incorrect if you are looking for people who have birthdays today (because birthdays are not dependant on year, but on month and day).

Comment: its working fine . getting the birthday list between given range any idea?

Comment: @Vino That's another question you should ask. If this answer has worked for you, then please upvote/mark it as correct and do the same for other answers on StackOverflow if they have managed to help you.

Comment: For getting range of dates, you should be using BETWEEN operator. But as Radu said, it's a new question altogether.

Comment: thanks to all for your comments

Comment: It works fine. Used it t sql server studio

Comment: THis worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [DATE OF BIRTH], Name
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE datepart(dd,[DATE OF BIRTH]) = datepart(dd,GETDATE()) 
AND datepart(mm,[DATE OF BIRTH]) = datepart(mm,GETDATE())
```

For getting list for a range of dates:

```
declare @StartDate DATE
declare @EndDate DATE

SELECT [DATE OF BIRTH], Name
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE 
datepart(dd,[DATE OF BIRTH]) between datepart(dd,@StartDate) 
AND datepart(dd,@EndDate)   

AND datepart(mm,[DATE OF BIRTH]) between datepart(mm,@StartDate) 
AND datepart(mm,@EndDate)
```